# How to get user sign up email address from Azure B2C with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2C tenant that is using the Signup/Sign in flow to let users register with their personal email. At sign up, users are asked to provide email, first/last names, phone, and a few custom fields we added. All fields are required in the flow.

I can see that customers are signing up and providing email addresses. In the B2C tenant users view, it shows them:
[image]

I've got a PowerShell script that can connect to the tenant and pull these user objects down:

```
Import-Module Az.Resources

Login-AzAccount

Connect-AzAccount -TenantId c4722b70-7f86-496e-a51f-f83dea9XXXXX

$Users = Get-AzADUser | select *

ForEach ($User in $Users)
{

 Write-Host $User

}
```

Most of the properties are blank, and the UPN doesn't show the email they signed up with - rather it shows a guid + the onmicrosoft domain:

```
OdataType   #microsoft.graph.user; 
PasswordProfile {}; 
Id  04aee807-61c8-40c1-956e-7757380XXXX; 
UserPrincipalName   04aee807-61c8-40c1-956e-77573801XXXX@b2cguest123.onmicrosoft.com; 
DisplayName DAVID H#####; 
GivenName   DAVID; 
Surname H#####;
AdditionalProperties    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]}
BusinessPhone   System.String[];
```

The fields you might expect to possibly contain an email are all null/blank (Mail, OtherMail, AdditionalProperties, ProxyAddress).

I know the data exists somewhere, how do I get it?

Comment: The following links may be of some help:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=powershell and https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/get-azureaduser/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD B2C user using Sign up and Sign in flow by providing personal email:

[image]

In the B2C tenant users view, I can find above user mail under User name:

[image]

You can find user **sign up email address** in **`identities`** field by running below MS Graph query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,identities
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get user **sign up email address** from Azure B2C with PowerShell, you can use below script by installing `Microsoft.Graph` module:

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Force
Connect-MgGraph -Scope User.Read.All -TenantId <b2c_tenant_id> 

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
Get-MgUser -Property "id,displayName,identities" | Select-Object   "id", "displayName", "identities"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I accepted this as-is, but since I'm using a b2c tenant it might be helpful to mention that I used the -TenantId parameter when calling Connect-MgGraph